# SLURM partition configuration: suspend and requeue

Tags: linux, slurm

I am struggling a bit to configure our SLURM server. I wanted to have several queues (partitions) so that the short queues had higher priority and jobs could enter immediately suspending or requeuing lower priority jobs.

The idea is to have 4 queues:

- infinite: Infinite time jobs. All nodes in. Lowest priority. If job in a higher priority queue needs some node, requeue job.
- batch: 24 hour jobs. All nodes in. Priority higher than above. If job in a higher priority queue needs some node, requeue job.
- short: 4 hour jobs. 3 nodes in (shared with previous partitions). Priority higher than above. If job in a higher priority queue needs some node, suspend job.
- cpupower: 1 hour jobs. 1 node (best one in our farm and shared with previous partitions). Highest priority. Jobs to this queue should enter unless there are too many jobs of this kind.

By looking at the manual I thought that the following would work, but jobs are never suspended or requeued.

```
PartitionName=infinite Nodes=ALL              Default=NO  MaxTime=INFINITE Priority=10 OverSubscribe=FORCE:1 PreemptMode=requeue State=UP
PartitionName=batch    Nodes=ALL              Default=YES MaxTime=24:00:00 Priority=20 OverSubscribe=FORCE:1 PreemptMode=requeue State=UP
PartitionName=short    Nodes=node[001,002,0032] Default=NO  MaxTime=4:00:00  Priority=30 OverSubscribe=FORCE:1 PreemptMode=suspend State=UP
PartitionName=cpupower Nodes=node003           Default=NO  MaxTime=1:00:00  Priority=40 OverSubscribe=NO      PreemptMode=off     State=UP
```

Maybe there is something else needed?

Comment: I think you're approaching this in a way that is not supported by how Slurm works.  Our configuration is that - there is one windfall default partition that all jobs can go into, and if a user needs a shorter time, or more resources than normal, those nodes are separate features/partitions.  Slurm (to my knowledge) does not have a feature that pre-empts a running job in favor of a new one.

Comment: Ok. I will need to re-read the documentation as this is not what I understood. Thanks.

Comment: Just in case someone relies on the above - slurm DOES support preemption - see https://slurm.schedmd.com/preempt.html